# Каким образом можно организовать нажатие на текст с последующими действиями?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в Unity, посему такой вопрос. Я пробовал это сделать через метод OnMouseDown(), но при нажатии на текст Play или Exit ничего не происходит, хотя если тот же код перенести на Cube, то все прекрасно срабатывает (в данном случае у меня просто должен выводиться текст) ([Пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7a0w.jpg)). Коллайдеры добавил, Ignore Raycast layer не стоит, библиотеку UnityEngine.UI подключил.

Comment: Попробуйте имплементировать вот этот [интерфейс](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) - он как раз таки предназначен для работы с UI элементами.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключи `using UnityEngine.EventSystems`, далее подключаешь интерфейс `IPointerClickHandler` и пишешь свой метод

```
void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData) 
    {
        //твой код
    }
```

Comment: Стоит - все равно не реагирует :(

Comment: Я изменил ответ. На этот раз рабочий способ

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, именно так и сделал. Комментатор выше тоже это подсказал :)